# One to One mapping

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table with two columns "*name*" and "*location*".

It consists of people name and places where they have travelled.

| name | location |
| --- | --- |
| Sandeep | Delhi |
| Sandeep | Jaipur |
| Nupur | Jammu |
| Nupur | Jaipur |
| Nupur | Delhi |
| Harsh | Jammu |

I want to output name of people in two columns "*Name A*" and "*Name B*" such that people in "*Name B*" would have travelled at least the same cities as people in "*Name A*".

Expected Output:

| NameA | NameB |
| --- | --- |
| Sandeep | Nupur |
| Harsh | Nupur |

I've tried with the following coding attempt:

```
SELECT u.source, 
       u.target 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS combine, 
             source,
             target 
      FROM  (SELECT a.name     AS source,
                    b.name     AS target, 
                    a.location AS location
             FROM A a JOIN A b ON (a.location = b.location AND a.name <> b.name))
      GROUP BY source,
               target ) u 
JOIN  (SELECT name, 
              COUNT(*) AS solo 
       FROM A 
       GROUP BY name            )v ON u.source = v.name where u.combine = v.solo;
```

It is giving me the required answer. Though is there a better approach to solve this problem?

See MTO's answer to this question to get more insight.

Comment: Tag only the database you are using.

Comment: To avoid ambiguity please add expected outcome and also what you have so far.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have updated the question and have added the expected outcome.

Comment: if the updates made you satisfied. Kindly remove the downvotes. I really need answer for this question.

Comment: Can you share your latest coding attempt at this problem? @Sandeep

Comment: @lemon I cannot do that because I have created this problem based on a situation I am facing right now in a more complex problem.

Comment: I thought may be we can use self join, but I have no idea how I am going to do that.

Comment: If this problem comes from a bigger problem, try attempting this simpler problem, then porting it into the bigger problem. The first attempt should always come from you, then we could fix your work here, in the best case possible you'll already come up with a great solution.

Comment: @lemon I have added my approach in the question. Kindly see if you have a better solution.

Comment: if the post will get reopened (no purpose for closure imo), I'll leave my idea+code in the answers section @Sandeep

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT l.name,
       r.name
FROM   (
         SELECT l.*,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS num_locations
         FROM   table_name l
       ) l
       INNER JOIN table_name r
       ON (l.location = r.location AND l.name <> r.name)
GROUP BY
       l.name,
       r.name
HAVING COUNT(r.name) = MAX(l.num_locations);
```

or, without the self-join, using a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT PRIOR name,
       name
FROM   (
  SELECT l.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS num_locations
  FROM   table_name l
)
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR location = location
AND    PRIOR name <> name
GROUP BY
       PRIOR name,
       name
HAVING COUNT(name) = MAX(PRIOR num_locations);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (name, location) AS
SELECT 'Sandeep', 'Delhi' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sandeep', 'Jaipur' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Nupur',   'Jammu' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Nupur',   'Jaipur' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Nupur',   'Delhi' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Harsh',   'Jammu' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | NAME | NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | Harsh | Nupur |
> | Sandeep | Nupur |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=00992a795d8f85de821902a00a98c4bd)*